# How to show multiple loading Skeleton screen on looping array in react using material ui Skeleton component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm dealing with the react project that fetches data through API endpoint. I'm using material-UI for UI components. I want to implement the Skeleton component from material-ui to show loading when waiting for the data to be fetched from the backend.

The problem is, I can show the skeleton when data is being fetched, but I want to show the skeleton component to be displayed for all the items in the array that are being looped through.

Here what is worked on

[image]

here what i want..

[image]

IF the api's returning the response with an array of consisting six objects, i want to show skeleton loading component to show six times on the screen.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of having a skeleton is to give the user a **preview** of how the UI might look like when the data is fetched so that it provides a good UX .

But how will the UI know that we need to render the 6 skeletons . This information has to come from the API . But by the time you do something like your `response.data.length` to determine the size , you already have the response in the UI. Why to show the `skeleton` when you already have the response ?. So IMHO we should not be focusing on matching the skeletons length with your response length. Just render the no of skeleton which looks good in the UI .

```
 if (loading) {
    return <ListSkeleton listsToRender={8} />; // pass the no you want as a prop
  }
```

**ListSkeleton**

```
 const ListSkeleton = ({listsToRender}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {Array(listsToRender)
        .fill(1)
        .map((card, index) => (
           // render your skeleton here
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```